# Finding a link for an embeded video which only appears after video starts playing?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to use python to download the video files for all the episodes of the show Unique Sweets which can be found here: 
http://www.cookingchanneltv.com/shows/unique-sweets/cooking--unique-sweets.html

I can't find the video link while inspecting elements of the page but if I view 'page info' and look at the media tab I can see the link to the video and that is only after I start playing the video in the page. Before actually starting to play the video there is a different link displayed as the video in the media tab.

Is there a way to automate the starting of the video and then parse the link even though I can't seem to find it when using firebug so that I can download the video?

Comment: What are you using to send call the URL?

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro this question is off topic